# How to address an earlier element in a list/string with for?

Tags: python

So my question is - I have a code like that:

```
test_text = "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"

for each in test_text:
   #do some stuff
```

And while it surely works for the letter that's currently "highlighted" by for, I can't do anything to the previous ones without having an additional variable that I would increment in each iteration so that I could address test_text[said_variable]. I mean - let's say that for every letter user wants, I have to print the letter that's five index places before the said letter - without the additional variable, I can't do this. Could someone please help? Can I address something prior (or after) to what for is now working on without having to play like that?

I'm sorry for the newbish question, but I'm just starting in Python and couldn't find anything on the matter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this without a second variable, but you don't have to manually increment it:

```
for i, each in enumerate(test_text):
    print each, test_text[i-5]
```

[*enumerate docs*](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Note that a negative list index will go to the end of the list, i.e. `test_text[-1]` will return the last character, so you'd have to add a check on `i-5` if you don't want this behavior.

Answer (score 4):

As Lenna posted, *enumerate* is a good way to track the position index while looping.

That said, your `text[i-5]` lookup will fail whenever `i < 5`.   Instead, try using a slices to access the range around `i`.

```
>>> test_text = "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
>>> for i, c in enumerate(test_text):
    print repr(c), "is surrounded by", repr(test_text[i-5:i+5])


'l' is surrounded by ''
'o' is surrounded by ''
'r' is surrounded by ''
'e' is surrounded by ''
'm' is surrounded by ''
' ' is surrounded by 'lorem ipsu'
'i' is surrounded by 'orem ipsum'
'p' is surrounded by 'rem ipsum '
's' is surrounded by 'em ipsum d'
'u' is surrounded by 'm ipsum do'
'm' is surrounded by ' ipsum dol'
' ' is surrounded by 'ipsum dolo'
'd' is surrounded by 'psum dolor'
'o' is surrounded by 'sum dolor '
'l' is surrounded by 'um dolor s'
'o' is surrounded by 'm dolor si'
'r' is surrounded by ' dolor sit'
' ' is surrounded by 'dolor sit '
's' is surrounded by 'olor sit a'
'i' is surrounded by 'lor sit am'
't' is surrounded by 'or sit ame'
' ' is surrounded by 'r sit amet'
'a' is surrounded by ' sit amet'
'm' is surrounded by 'sit amet'
'e' is surrounded by 'it amet'
't' is surrounded by 't amet'
```

Comment: See the slice examples at the beginning of the Python tutorial:  http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

Comment: Oh, that - didn't even know it's named "slices" :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nevetheless, the `enumerate` function cannot handle (easily) some basic task relative to earlier elements, for instance, finding the incresingness of an integer list whereas the `range + len` non-idiom handles the case in a natural way : `all(L[i+1]>=L[i] for i in range(len(L)-1))`. For sure `enumerate` can proceed with `all(L[i+1]>=L[i] for (i,_) in enumerate(L) if i+1<len(L))` but the conditional is ugly and inefficient.